# RegEx strip html tags problem

Tags: html, regex

I've tried to strip html tags using regex replace with pattern "<[^>]*>" from word generated html that looks like this:

<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:st1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"&gt;

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 11 (filtered medium)">
<!--[if !mso]>
<style>

**v:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}**

**o:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}**

**w:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}**

**.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}**

</style>
<![endif]--><o:SmartTagType
 namespaceuri="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:smarttags" name="place"
 downloadurl="http://www.5iantlavalamp.com/"/&gt;
<!--[if !mso]>
<style>

**st1:*{behavior:url(#default#ieooui) }**

</style>
<![endif]-->
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:Tahoma;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman";}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:windowtext;}
span.EmailStyle18
    {mso-style-type:personal-reply;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:navy;}
@page Section1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.25in 1.0in 1.25in;}
div.Section1
    {page:Section1;}
-->
</style>

</head>

Everything works fine except for the bolded lines above, anybody got ideas how to match the them to?

Thanks,

Aleksandar

Comment: You should put your HTML code into the CODE block (101/010 button). It makes reading it much easier

Answer (score 3):

Your regex does not take into account that comments can contain `>` characters that do not terminated the comment.  Try this regex:

```
<!--.*?-->|<[^>]*>
```

You'll have to turn on the option to make `.` match line breaks.  How to do that depends on the application or programming language you're using this regex with.  E.g. in Perl you'd use the `/s` flag.  In .NET you'd set `RegexOptions.SingleLine`.

Comment: *Your* regex doesn't take into account that attribute values of HTML tags can contain '>', as in `<img alt="&lt;enter text here>">`

Comment: My answer only explains why Aleksandar's regex doesn't do what he expects and only provides a solution for that specific problem on his specific example.  There are a lot of things my regex doesn't take into account.  If MS Word did not put its `<style>` tags inside comments then my regex would have the same problem as Aleksandar's.  If you want to take everything into account, then you need a full HTML parser and knowledge about the meaning of specific tags (e.g. `<style>` and `<script>` tags do not contain dipslayable content).

Answer (score 0):

People generally advise the use of a parser instead of regex when dealing with HTML.

In case you *have* to use a regex :)  you could use-

```
<style>.*?</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

[You can't use Regular expressions to parse HTML (or XML for that matter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454).

Comment: He's not trying to parse it, he's trying to get rid of it.

I happen to agree with you -- the OP is going to run into the same kind of trouble -- but that link doesn't effectively make that point.

Comment: Depends on the situation.  If the OP just has to clean out a few HTML files in a text editor, a simple regex or two may do the job just fine.